# How can I smooth the top side of this ring?

Tags: modeling

I want to smooth the top side of this ring:

[image]
[image]

This is how it looks like after rendering:
[image]

The mesh of the top side of the ring is very obvious in the rendered image and basically this is my problem.

I am a beginner in Blender but I have tried everything I know. First off, I have made the selection of the top side of the ring manually in edit mode because couldn't find an easier way. Then, I have tried to subdevide the selection but it won't subdevide anything except for some faces. I have tried `ctrl+R` to make cuts but it doesn't work.

The ring is the result of an extruded 2D vector and then sliced vertically using Knife project tool and then bent 360 degrees using simple deform modifier

My question is **how can I smooth just the top side of the ring without the edges?**

Comment: Sounds like you may have duplicate vertices, so remove them first. Then you can either subdivide, bevel and/or select smooth shading for the selected faces.

Comment: @gtzkw I have already removed duplicates but subdivide still didn't work for most of the selected faces. I have tried smooth shading for the selected faces but it makes the face unrealistically smooth. Can I control how much smooth the selected faces should be?

Comment: By the looks of it the topology is really bad, ngons and possibly disconnected face, which is why subsurf doesn't work. For the other part see @moonboots answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have these 2 solutions:

- Smooth your object in the *Tools* panel, and in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Normals*, enable *Auto-Smooth*, set the value under which the angles smooth.

[image]

- Create a bevel all along the angles, thin enough to keep them sharp, it may need a bit of knife work if you have triangles or ngons. After that, smooth your object in the *Tools* panel, and give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. If you're supposed to 3D print the object, I guess you just need to apply the *Subsurf*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you the first option worked for me. Do you know how can I make the selection (top of the ring) in an easier way. I have made the selection manually using the Circle tool.

Comment: if your topology was good you could do it with a simple edge loop select (alt + left-click), but as the series of faces on the top are not always quads (I see some triangles and ngons) edge loop select can't work properly, so I'm not sure there's any easy solution, except fixing this and making only quads on the top. A trick that could help though: once you've selected all these faces, you can create a vertex group so that next time you don't have to reselect them manually.

Comment: I'm sure there was a way to make a good topology from the start but I guess it's another topic   ;)

Comment: that said you could try to select one of the top faces, and press shift G (Select Similar) > Normals, then play with the parameter (threshold), it might work to a certain extent

Answer (score 0):

Relatively straightforward with a couple of modifiers.

I did this freehand but you would be better with a reference image and taking more time but the process would be the same.

Imagine the shape cut in half and flat.

[image]

Make sure the pivot is on the right hand side and that the verts on the right line up with a scale to zero on the x in the image shown.

Add a mirror modifier and apply followed by some extra edge cuts as shown

[image]

Add a bend deformer and wrap the object 360 degrees

[image]

In edit mode extrude the shape x 3 making sure the first and last extrude are shallow giving a supporting edge.

[image]

Add a subsurf modifier x 2 and adjust verts as required.

[image]

This process will work the same with your reference.